# Preview ignores leading whitespace

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, whitespace

Markdown source:

```
flush left

 indent

  more indent
```

Renders correctly as:

> flush left
>
> indent
>
> more indent

But [edit this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/353979/edit), and notice that the leading whitespace is ignored in the preview:
[image: screenshot of edit preview]